# How to Link Drop Down List Validation to Column Comparison

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have multiple rows with drop down lists with two items (applicable and non-applicable), and corresponding categorization values for each drop down list (Low/Moderate/High). I have a formula that compares the values in the categorization columns and returns the highest. I'm trying to make it so that the comparison only functions when "applicable" is selected in a drop down list, but my excel skills are novice at best.

This is the formula I'm using for the comparison:

```
=INDEX($S$2:$S$5, MATCH(MAX(F4:F212), $T$2:$T$5,0))

=IFERROR(IF(D7=$Q$1,INDEX($T$2:$T$5,MATCH(E7,$S$2:$S$5,0)),""),"")

=INDEX($S$2:$S$5, MATCH(MAX(F4:F212), $T$2:$T$5,0))
```

The formula returns the highest value, but for the entire column rather than the selected drop down menu. I'm missing the step that connects the two.

[image]

*EDIT: I've added a snip of the desired results as an example (I haven't hidden the cells I'm using for enumeration). What I would like is for every row that's selected as applicable to have it's individual values compared, and then the overall highest of those values is output to the right. I've gotten the comparison to work, but it does a comparison for each column with data in it because I'm not sure how to use the drop down lists as a toggle.

[image]

Comment: Can you show any mock-up or screenshots of the data?  There're several ways you can do this, but one may be more appropriate than the other, e.g., `=if(b2="applicable",sumifs(),0)` as opposed to counting, etc.

Comment: I've edited in a screenshot for reference.

Comment: Your screenshot did not demonstrate what you want clearly. You may need to add or update your screenshot to include the desired outcome and specify where you got stuck.

Comment: Added an additional screenshot with the desired outcome. I appreciate the assistance so far!